# convert my date to timestamp in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to convert my date to timestamp i dont know where im doing wrong.Any suggestion please ?

```
var dates = '27-04-2015';
var date1 = new Date(dates).getTime();
alert(date1);
```

Comment: console.log(+(new Date(dates)));

Comment: Parameter passed to new Date() is invalid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parameter you passed in the `new Date('27-04-2015')` is not valid. Use sepeartor '/' for change date format and send to the `new Date('27/04/2015')`.

```
var dates = '27-04-2015';
var dates1 = dates.split("-");
var newDate = dates1[1]+"/"+dates1[0]+"/"+dates1[2];
alert(new Date(newDate).getTime());
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rem19u0z/)

Answer (score 1):

`Date` constructor takes argument in `mm-dd-yyyy` format, try this

```js
var timeStamp = function(str) {
  return new Date(str.replace(/^(\d{2}\-)(\d{2}\-)(\d{4})$/,
    '$2$1$3')).getTime();
};
alert(timeStamp('27-04-2015'));
```

Here, I had used RegExp to swap the format from `dd-mm-yyyy` to `mm-dd-yyyy`. So `'27-04-2015'` gives `'04-27-2015'`. In the expression `(\d{2}\-)(\d{2}\-)(\d{4})`, `\d` denotes integer, `{}` for length, `()` for grouping, `\` to escape special characters like `-`.